# Multiprocessing inside python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-variable

I'm trying to do parallel computation to speed up a for loop (I'm already using itertools, I need more speed since I do the for loop several times). I am new to multiprocessing. I have checked several questions on stack overflow and I tried to solve my problem however I still have some difficulties. I am creating shared variables (self.A, self.B, self.C) so that multiprocessing is done efficiently. However, I think I am doing something wrong since when I check my variables after the computation I see that they did not change. My code is a bit complicated so the below code is a sample code which demonstrate my problem. Thanks for your help!

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Pool
from ctypes import c_double
import itertools

class F():
     def __init__(self, num_process=4):
        self.num_process = num_process
        self.idx = list(itertools.product(range(5), range(10)))
        self.A = np.zeros((5, 10)) 
        if self.num_process > 1:
            self.A = np.frombuffer(Array(c_double, self.A.flat, lock=False))
            self.A.resize(5,10)

     def solve(self):       
         self.B = np.zeros((10, 5, 10)) 
         self.C = np.zeros((10, 5, 10)) 
         if self.num_process > 1:
            self.B = np.frombuffer(Array(c_double, self.B.flat, lock=False))
            self.B.resize(10,5,10)
            self.C = np.frombuffer(Array(c_double, self.C.flat, lock=False))
            self.C.resize(10,5,10)
         print('Before=',self.A,self.B,self.C)
         for i in range(10):   
             if self.num_process == 1:
                 for (k,l) in self.idx:    
                     self.B[i,k,l]=1
                     self.C[i,k,l]=1

             else:
                 workers = []
                 for worker_num in range(self.num_process):
                     worker = Process(target=F.update, 
                                         args=(i, worker_num, self.num_process,
                                               self.idx, self.A, self.B, self.C))
                     workers.append(worker)
                     worker.start()
                 for worker in workers:
                     worker.join() 
         print('After=',self.A,self.B,self.C)

     @staticmethod 
     def update( i, worker_num, num_process, idx, A, B, C):
        start_num = int(len(idx) * (worker_num/num_process))
        end_num = int(len(idx) * ((worker_num+1)/num_process))
        for j in range(start_num, end_num):
            k,l = idx[j]
            B[i,k,l]=min(2,A[k,l])
            C[i,k,l]=2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    var=F()
    var.solve()
```

When I print my variables after the computation I see that they did not change.

**UPDATE**
I was able to correct my code and do multiprocessing using the below code. My mistake, as Ricky Kim pointed out, was that I was not creating shared variables. The below code achieves this however it is still slowwww much slower than using 1 process (to do the same operations of course).  Any ideas on how to make multiprocessing faster and more effective. Thanks!

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Pool
from ctypes import c_double
import itertools

class F():
     def __init__(self, num_process=4):
        self.num_process = num_process
        self.idx = list(itertools.product(range(5), range(10)))
        self.A = np.zeros((5, 10)) 

     def solve(self):       
         B_shared = Array(c_double, 10*5*10)
         C_shared = Array(c_double, 10*5*10)
         self.B = np.frombuffer(B_shared.get_obj())
         self.B = self.B.reshape(10,5,10)
         self.C = np.frombuffer(C_shared.get_obj())
         self.C = self.C.reshape(10,5,10)
         print('Before=',self.A,self.B,self.C)
         for i in range(10):   
             if self.num_process == 1:
                 # perform some expensive operation
                 for (k,l) in self.idx:    
                     self.B[i,k,l]=1
                     self.C[i,k,l]=1

             else:
                 workers = []
                 for worker_num in range(self.num_process):
                     worker = Process(target=self.update, 
                                         args=(i, worker_num, self.num_process, B_shared, C_shared))
                     workers.append(worker)
                     worker.start()
                 for worker in workers:
                     worker.join() 
         print('After=',self.A,self.B,self.C)


     def update(self, i, worker_num, num_process, B_shared, C_shared):
        B = np.frombuffer(B_shared.get_obj())
        B = B.reshape((10,5,10)) 
        C = np.frombuffer(B_shared.get_obj())
        C = C.reshape((10,5,10)) 
        start_num = int(len(self.idx) * (worker_num/num_process))
        end_num = int(len(self.idx) * ((worker_num+1)/num_process))
        for j in range(start_num, end_num):
            # perform some expensive operation
            k,l = self.idx[j]
            B[i,k,l]=min(2,self.A[k,l])
            C[i,k,l]=2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    var=F()
    var.solve()
```

Comment: In your `update` function, you change `A`, `B`, `C`, which you do not return so you have not done anything with `self.A`, `self.B`, `self.C`

Comment: But I have created `self.A`, `self.B`, `self.C` as shared variables so I expected them to change inside the `update` function. I am not sure how to pass `self.A`, `self.B`, `self.C` to `update` function since I cannot have something like `def update( self, i, worker_num, num_process):` and then use  `self.A`, `self.B`, `self.C` to the updates. This is because `self` will be considered as a variable when I call `Process(target=F.update, args=(i, worker_num, self.num_process))`. And if I return `A`, `B`, `C` as you suggest how do I update `self.A`, `self.B`, `self.C` with them inside `solve`?

Comment: Everything you have said is incorrect. You did not create shared variables between processes, and `self` is an instance of the class, which can be considered a variable. In fact, you have done this for your `solve` function. I suggest you read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: Thanks! After reading the link you provided I was able to fix my mistakes.  I have updated my original post with the new code. However my code is still sloww much slower than using only one process. Any ideas on what is making it slow or how to make it faster? Thanks man.

Comment: You should probably look into Multithreading